# SerialPort the same input and output buffer?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Visual studio 2010 express, WindowsFormsApplication

I have those two pieces of code in my application. First one should send some data on the serial port every second. The second one should recieve data from serial port. **At the moment, I have no device connected to serial port**. Therefore, datarecieved handler should never be triggered, and no data should be recieved.
My problem is that I recieve the data I sent in the first piece of code. Is that a normal behaviour? Is there any way to prevent that behaviour? Would it be different if I connected device to serial port?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort.Write(dataToSend, 0, 1);
    }

private void datarecievedhandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort.Read(dataToRead, 0, 1);
        MessageBox.Show("Something is recieved!");
    }
```

Comment: what is `e.EventType` ? is it perhaps EOF?

Comment: sorry, i am still a beginner in this area...I dont understand a question

Comment: In your `datarecievedhandler` you get `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e`; on `e` is a value `e.EventType` that is intended to help you understand the event. Simply... if you add a break point; what is `e.EventType` ?

Comment: type--System.IO.Ports.SerialData, value--Chars

Answer (score 2):

If there is nothing connected to the port, and you are receiving echo, it means that you most probably opened a wrong COM port (like one of the Bluetooth ports, a modem, or something similar), which has echo enabled by default.

Open the Device Manager in Windows Control Panel, look under Ports and make sure that you open the correct COM port.

Comment: thanks, that seems to be a problem...when i conneceted the device, and opened a different port, everything was ok;)

Answer (score 1):

You must first test if a device is connected with the protocol you use to communicate with your device.

For example, try to send a "hello", and wait for a ACK. If you get a timeout, that mean that no device is connected.

If your device does not support "hello/ack" kind of message, just try reading data and see if it time out.

Comment: thanks... i dont have to test if the device is connected...i know it is not because i did not connect it to port. I just tought that if there is no device connected, datarecieved handler should never be raised. Am i right?